# Android WebView - background PNG image causes a thin white line to appear

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview which displays a simple enough HTML with a header that's "casting a shadow" using a PNG image of a translucent gradient. Everywhere, except Androids WebView it looks just fine, blending seamlessly.

On Android however, it's causing a very thin white line to appear on the edges of the container that's using the PNG as background. Once PNG is removed the line disappears.

I'm wondering - is it a known issue on Android, or did I manage to stumble on one PNG image that wants to be special?

**UPD: Screenshot**

[image: The line is visible in the areas marked green.]

The line is visible in the areas marked green. The grey bar that "casts the shadow" is position absolute at z-index 10, while the red bar is position absolute at z-index 1.

Comment: Try with a completly different PNG (just for the fun of it) and se if the same line appears.

Comment: No line... Goddamnit... I guess I have to replace the PNG then.

Comment: hehe always try to point at yourself before pointing at others :p

Comment: Question is why did the same PNG file behave normally EVERYWHERE except Android.

Comment: I can't tell without the original image, but if you put it up I can try to look and maybe give an answer to the question in general :)